# Add Header Title in a TableView for JSON data received using Paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, paging

I have searched a lot but i am unable to find the solution, can someone guide me for the following solution.

JSON Data Received using Paging for page1 and so on.

```
"ErrorCode":null,
"Message":"Success",
"Data":[
{
  "ProductID":1,
  "ProductName" :"Mango",
  "ProductCategory" :"Fruits"
},
{
  "ProductID":2,
  "ProductName" :"Banana",
  "ProductCategory" :"Fruits"
},
{
  "ProductID":3,
  "ProductName" :"Fanta",
  "ProductCategory" :"Drinks"
},
{
  "ProductID":4,
  "ProductName" :"Pepsi",
  "ProductCategory" :"Drinks"
},
{
  "ProductID":5,
  "ProductName" :"Carrot",
  "ProductCategory" :"Vegetables"
}
```

Above is the sample data where for fruits when I scrolled up, in return i get multiple records while using pagination, this is done correctly and the data is showing properly in a tableview for all the records available as shown above.

My requirement is, i want to show header for each product category where title will be shown as fruits for example and all related products will be shown under. i could have done it if the data is received all at once but when we are using paging then i am not sure the next page data i receive in a json response will have another product category or the same.

Please clarify if my question is not clear. I hope the person who has done paging knows what i am talking about.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have searched a lot but i am unable to find the solution"  How long have you spent?  Half a second?  If so, keep searching.  Or talk to a friend who has basic knowledge about running search with a search engine.  SO isn't a search service.

Comment: Do you need the code in Objective C or swift?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a datasource e.g `self.dataSourceDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];` and filter your response like below (`responseDictionary` holds JSON response)

```
- (void)catagorizeData:(NSDictionary *)responseDictionary
{
    for (NSDictionary *productDictionary in [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"Data"]) {
        NSMutableArray *eachCategoryArray = [self.dataSourceDictionary objectForKey:[productDictionary objectForKey:@"productCategory"]];
        if (eachCategoryArray == nil) {
            eachCategoryArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            [eachCategoryArray addObject:productDictionary];
            [self.dataSourceDictionary setObject:eachCategoryArray forKey:[productDictionary objectForKey:@"productCategory"]];
        }else{
            [eachCategoryArray addObject:productDictionary];
        }
    }
}
```

Call the above method each time you get response for paging.
Now show the filtered data in sectioned `tableview` like below:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.dataSourceDictionary count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *key = [[self.dataSourceDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[self.dataSourceDictionary objectForKey:key] count];
}
```

N.B This code is only to give you a basic idea.